# Directory size not consistent with what it should be

Tags: java, android, io

I want to calculate the cache size of my app.
I used `du -sh` in the *cache* folder of my app and it said *71M*.
Then I went to the application manager to see my app's cache size it also told me *71M*.

But when I tried to get the size programmatically, whenever I use the recursive `getFolderSize()` or the apache's commons-io `FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory()`, it all turned out to be *54M* after I divided 1024*1024.

That confuses me.

Comment: Which value do you consider 'what it should be' ?

Comment: Please determine the file size of all files in that folder. Add them up. What is the value?

Comment: Ever heard of block oriented media?

Comment: I think the size should be 71M instead of 54M, and I don't know what causes this difference. @greenapps

Comment: I think that both are valid. But please do the addition. And google for blok oriented media.

Comment: Write a file with size of one byte to a medium. And see that free space became 32KB less. Write yet a file of 10KB and see that free space is again 32KB less. Every file occupies blocks of 32KB. (The 32 can be 16 too). Like writing a book and every chapter has to start on a new page.

Comment: Thank your for letting me know this :) @greenapps